# Is it OK to use "heck" in public occasions?

Tags: politeness, formal-language, informal-language, colloquial-language

The dictionary gives the following definitions:

- [fuck](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fuck):

  - to have sex with someone.
  - used when expressing extreme anger, or to add force to what is being said.
- [heck](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/heck):

  - an expression of usually slight anger or surprise, or a way of adding force to a statement, question, etc.

While not listed, is there an implication that *heck* has a meaning of *to have slight sex with someone* which makes it inappropriate to be used in public occasions?

Comment: Why do you think there's a connection between these two words? Also, what's "slight sex"?

Comment: @Catija Anger, adding force, 2 letters in common, and how often I hear them.

Comment: No. 'heck' has nothing to do with 'sex'. You would never hear these sentences: "Heck you." or "Wanna heck?".

Comment: @holydragon The most often I heard was like *what the fuck* and *what the heck*, which made me think they might be forte and piano versions of the same thing. But you are right that I didn't seem to have heard *Heck you*.

Comment: Upvote for "slight sex". This is a great question, made me laugh. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is there an implication that heck has a meaning of to have slight sex with someone

Nope.  *Heck* is a neutered version of *hell* (which isn't too vulgar these days, but still "adults only" for the most part) and has nothing to do with *fuck* (which is still considered very vulgar).

> Why the hell is she here? (inappropriate for children to say)
>
> Why the heck is she here? (you could say this in front of children)

*Screw* is a popular "censorship-friendly" substitution for *fuck* and can be used in many but not all the ways *fuck* can.

For instance - you can say *the fuck* in the same way as you would say *the hell* - and *fuck* is much stronger ...

> Why the fuck is she here? (vulgar and expressing a lot of hostility, cover the children's ears ...)

In this case *the fuck* has no connection to sex but is just an adverbial intensifier.  You cannot use *screw* here.  However, as seen above, you can use *the heck*.

Comment: Is this true only in American English or English in general: *Heck is a neutered version of hell*? And most importantly, is it OK to *heck* in public, such as when giving a speech or being interviewed by a news press? Is *in front of children* more or less strict than *in public*?

Comment: *Heck* is fine to say in public.  But note that *heck* is not a verb, there's no such thing as *hecking* anyone - *the heck* is valid though.

Comment: OK, thank you the affirmative answer. By *heck* in public I mean to use this word in public, not necessarily as a verb, though.

Comment: I would like to add that *hell* is only considered "adults only" in America. In the UK at least it's completely innocuous.

Comment: I think the [linked page](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/heck#american-english-1-1-1) in the OP's question adds to their confusion. The first entry under Examples for 'heck' is "Did we heck", which makes it sound like a verb.

Comment: @Omegastick Does this mean *heck* is the same as *hell*, or there's simply no *heck* in UK, or whatever I can't imagine?

Comment: @Cyker *Heck* in the UK is exactly the same as *hell* IMO in terms of severity. However, *hell* has an actual meaning (the biblical location) while *heck* is just used as an incredibly mild expletive.